# In Excel, highlight a cell (yellow) when the value of the cell just below it is anything other than "Not Required"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to highlight a cell (yellow) when the value of the cell just below it is anything other than "Not Required". Other areas of the workbook when checked, change the value from "Not Required" to something else. The first page is a summary and highlighting shows the make of the part to be furnished and highlighting it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with conditional formatting, but unless you want to bring your spreadsheet to a crawl, you should NOT apply this to a whole worksheet, just a limited area.

- Select the area that you want to apply the formatting to, let's say C2 to E40.
- C2 is now the active cell. This detail is important.
- create a new rule and use a formula to determine the format
- the formula will be `=$C3<>"Not Required"` Note that the reference to C3 has a $ sign in front of the C but not in front of the 3. That means that the fomula will always evaluate column C in the current row.
- pick a format, e.g. a yellow fill
- confirm all dialogs.

This format will now be applied to all the cells from C2 to E40 when the cell in column C and one row below the cell's row has a text other than "Not Required".

Adjust the ranges to suit your needs. When you define the formula, you need to use the row number of the currently active cell.

Comment: if that resolves you issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. if it doesn't, let me know and I will follow up.

Comment: Hmm... is pressing F4 to get `$C3` available in this dialog?

Comment: Yes. But you can also just type the dollar sign, the C and the 3

Comment: As typing is impaired by the fact that *all* cursor movements is used to insert cell references: All other help (e.g. F4) is a must.

Comment: @Hannu, not quite. You can hit F2 to toggle between selection mode and typing mode in the formula box. In typing mode you can use arrow keys, home, end, etc to navigate inside the formula box. Only in selection mode will arrow keys insert cell references.

Comment: Ahh... love that. I'm a long time Excel hacker, haven't laid my eyes on anything telling about F2 in this context.

Comment: @Hannu, it's not very well documented. It also works in other dialogs where the arrow keys perform selections, e.g. the Name Manager, chart series dialogs, etc.